# SQL Server Transaction inside stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose, i have two tables `Product` and `ProductSales`.

`Product` table has:

```
ProductID(int)(pk)
Name(varchar2)
UnitPrice(float) 
ProductAvailable(int)
```

`ProductSales` table has:

```
ProductSalesID(int)(pk)
ProductID(int)
Quantity(int)
```

I want to create a transaction inside stored procedure that first checks if the `Quantity` is less than `ProductAvailable`. If it is greater then `Rollback` the transaction else Deduct the `Quantity`(given by user) from `ProductAvailable` and also insert into `ProductSales` table.
how can i solve the scenario using SQL Server

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Please format your question.

Comment: you don't need a transaction to do that. your question does not make sense...

Comment: Do you really need a transaction for this. Can't you just add a where clause to UPDATE... WHERE (... Product.ProductAvailable < @Quantity), then if it's successful deduct the amount?

Comment: I see possible concurrency issue. If first thread checks the value and it's ok, then second checks value and it's ok, then every of them substract Quantity from ProductAvailable, it might end in negative available products

Comment: @giammin, Tanner. Of course you need a transaction! Otherwise, you can get a situation where a table [Product] updated and insert in table [ProductSales] does not occur (Clien connection lost, deadlock, restart server, etc.). You get data inconsistency

Comment: @AlexK as he stated in the question the insert is after the transaction

Comment: @giammin This makes no sense. And I see in the question:  Create a transaction ...check...deduct ... and ... insert... And of course, the transaction should be committed at the end of the procedure

Answer (score 1):

Solution for concurrent updates:

```
-- Test Data
CREATE TABLE Product (
    ProductID int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    ,Name varchar(256) NOT NULL
    ,UnitPrice money NOT NULL
    ,ProductAvailable int NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE ProductSales (
    ProductSalesID int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    ,ProductID int NOT NULL
    ,Quantity int NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO Product (Name, UnitPrice, ProductAvailable)
VALUES ('Prod1', 5.0, 10)
    ,('Prod2',6.0, 5)
GO
```

First variant - [MSDN OUTPUT Clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sale 
    @ProductID int
    ,@Quantity int
AS
BEGIN
    IF @Quantity <= 0 RETURN -1;

    -- atomic operation
    UPDATE Product
        SET ProductAvailable = ProductAvailable - @Quantity
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ProductID, @Quantity INTO ProductSales (ProductID, Quantity)
    WHERE ProductID = @ProductID
        AND ProductAvailable >= @Quantity;

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RETURN -1;
END
GO
```

But it has limitation - **output_table cannot**:

- Have enabled triggers defined on it.
- Participate on either side of a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
- Have CHECK constraints or enabled rules.

Second variant - [MSDN Transaction Statements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174377.aspx)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sale2
    @ProductID int
    ,@Quantity int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ProcID CHAR(36) = NEWID()
            ,@TranCount Int = @@TranCount
            ,@ProductAvailable int
            ,@errorMessage nvarchar(4000)
            ,@errorSeverity int
            ,@errorState int
            ,@ReturnCode int = -1;

    IF @Quantity <= 0 RETURN -1;

    IF (@TranCount = 0)
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    ELSE
        SAVE TRANSACTION @ProcID;

    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT @ProductAvailable = ProductAvailable 
        FROM Product WITH (XLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
        WHERE ProductID = @ProductID;

        -- Record is locked, you can do any checks here
        IF @ProductAvailable >= @Quantity
            BEGIN
                UPDATE Product
                    SET ProductAvailable = ProductAvailable - @Quantity
                WHERE ProductID = @ProductID;

                INSERT INTO ProductSales (ProductID, Quantity)
                    VALUES(@ProductID, @Quantity);

                SET @ReturnCode  = 1;
            END
        ELSE
            SET @ReturnCode  = -1;

        IF (@TranCount = 0)
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF (@TranCount = 0)
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        ELSE
            IF (XACT_STATE() <> -1)
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION @ProcID;

        SELECT @errorMessage = 'Error in [Sale2]: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE(), @errorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @errorState = ERROR_STATE();
        RAISERROR (@errorMessage, @errorSeverity, @errorState);
        SET @ReturnCode  = -1;
    END CATCH

    RETURN @ReturnCode;
END
GO
```

Check result

```
-- Test
DECLARE @RetCode int

EXEC @RetCode = Sale @ProductID = 1, @Quantity = 7
SELECT @RetCode as RetCode

EXEC @RetCode = Sale2 @ProductID = 1, @Quantity = 2
SELECT @RetCode as RetCode

EXEC @RetCode = Sale @ProductID = 2, @Quantity = 7
SELECT @RetCode as RetCode
GO
SELECT * FROM ProductSales
SELECT * FROM Product
GO
```

Comment: After 10 years i saw this answer and is so complete and no vote. No vote until now.
Thank you